# ¿Cómo puedo obtener una columna de un DataGridVIew y guardarla en un arreglo?

Tags: c#, array, datagridview

Cómo puedo obtener una columna especifica de un datagridview, guardarla en un arreglo separado por comas, para luego enviarla a una base de datos así mismo, en una sola línea separado por comas.

**CONTEXTO:**

Necesito guardar la columna "HDR" en un arreglo. El resultado que espero es poderlo llevar a sql así: 7004419,7004419,7004419,7004419,7004419,7004419.

[image: Necesito guardar en el arreglo la columna HDR]

Agradezco me ayuden indicándome cuando el campo sea solo números y cuando sea solo texto.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: es un windows form o un wpf?

Comment: es Windows Form.

Comment: porque queres hacer eso??? no deberias guardar esos datos todos en la misma columna.. deberian estar en una tabla aparte.. imaginate tratar de borrar uno, o agregar otro, o cuando quieras volver a mostrar esta tabla asi??? mas alla de eso, como estas cargando esta grid???